# Cannot post dropdown list selected value to server using $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first development using **JQuery (jquery-3.0.0.min.js)** and Javascript. 
I am creating a simple web form connected to a database via Web API.
The form includes some input text tags and two select tags. 
I am posting the form data using `$.ajax` method.
When I submit the form the values in the textboxes are correctly posted to the server but the selected values always result null.
Here is a piece of the HTML code:

```
<form name="modulo" id="modulo">
                ....
                <div class="field">
                    <label id="mailLbl" for="mail">Mail:</label>
                    <input id="mail" type="text" name="mail" required="required" />
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label id="CDselectLBL" for="CDselect">Centro di Costo</label>
                    <select id="CDselect" class="DropDownList" name="CDselect"></select>

                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label id="FINALITAselectLBL" for="FINALITAselect">Finalità</label>
                    <select id="FINALITAselect" class="DropDownList" name="FINALITAselect"></select>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label id="rif_studio_cliLbl" for="rif_studio_cli">Riferimento Studio Clinico:</label>
                    <input id="rif_studio_cli" type="text" name="rif_studio_cli" />
                </div> </form>
```

.. and here is the `$.Ajax` call:

```
$('#modulo').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'api/richiestes', // the local url where I want to POST
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            data: $('#modulo').serialize(),
        })
          // using the done promise callback
          .done(function (data) {
              console.log(data);

                           });
    });
```

Here is the form data (copied from Chrome DevTools):

> mail : tom.cat@google.com 
>   CDselect:10A0003 - GESTIONE FINANZIARIA
>   FINALITAselect:Studio clinico approvato da Comitato Etico
>   rif_studio_cli:sfvsdfv

Here is the preview of the request data being sent  (also copied from Chrome DevTools):

> mail : "tom.cat@google.com" 
>  CDC : null
>  finalità : null 
> rif_studio_cli : "sfvsdfv"

Can you help me understand what is wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance for your time and kindness

Comment: Option values of the two select tags come from the same database via Web API and $.Ajax GET

Comment: From [jQuery.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) documentation, only "successful" controls are serialized. A select control is successful only if an option was selected. Maybe this is your case?

Comment: Maybe you could also attach a snapshot of your HTML just before the submit is sent so we can check the state of your form controls.

Comment: Do you mean this?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B31H4lpkUyqZRDlsYlBMck5rTlE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse you dont have any option element in your select control. You need to add the option and then selected one. e.g.

I have created a plunker code for you.

https://plnkr.co/edit/L5SyOdU8hnEKdrKitmcL?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($('#modulo').serialize());
});
});
```

html is as provided by you on the comments above but i have removed the input boxes to simplify the page.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I feed the select tag with options like this:
 $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "api/vCDCs",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        //   data: query,
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (i) {
                $("#CDselect").append($("<option></option>").val(result[i].DescrizioneCentroDiCosto).text(result[i].DescrizioneCentroDiCosto));
            });
        },
        failure: function () {
            alert("Error");
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });

Comment: i am able to get the values of the drop down list, updating the answer with details.